# Two orbit equations: can them be used to prove some claim?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Given a finite group $G$, the Class Equation can be gotten by considering the action of $G$ on itself by conjugation. If $H\le G$, then we can consider the action of $H$ on $G$ by conjugation, which -unless I'm mistaken- leads to the following orbit equation:

$$|G|=|C_G(H)|+\sum_{a\in \{Orbits'\space reps\}}\frac{|H|}{|C_G(a)\cap H|} \tag 1$$

where:

- "$Orbits$" (capital "O") stands for the orbits (under this action) of size bigger than $1$.
- $C_G(H)$ is the centralizer of $H$ in $G$.

If, in addition, $H\unlhd G$, then we can consider also the action of $G$ on $H$ by conjugation, which -again if I did things properly- leads to this other orbit equation:

$$|H|=|H \cap Z(G)|+\sum_{h \in \{Orbits \space rep's\}}\frac{|G|}{|C_G(h)|} \tag 2$$

where, again, "$Orbits$" (capital "O") stands for the orbits (under this action) of size bigger than $1$.

In spite of the popularity of the Class Equation, I never happened to see any utilization of its "variations" $(1)$ and $(2)$ (or the correct versions of them, if some mistake is there).

> Is there any practical application of the orbit equations $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Comment: Isn’t your $K_G(H)$ the same as $C_G(H)$, the centralizer of $H$? If $a\in K_G(H)$, then $H\subseteq C_G(a)$, so $ah=ha$ for all $h\in H$, hence $a\in C_G(H)$. If $a\in C_G(H)$, then $ah=ha$ for all $h\in H$, so $H\subseteq C_G(a)$, hence $a\in K_G(H)$....

Comment: What do you mean by "practical"? These come up all the time when considering group actions.

Comment: I mean with some application as the Class Equation has, such as the center of finite $p$ groups being nontrivial, etc.

Comment: Some people define the class equation for a group acting on an arbitrary set, and your first statement is then called the conjugacy class equation. The case of $H$ acting on $G$ by conjugation is then just a case of the former. As @MorganRodgers says, almost any time you have group actions these equations can give some interesting information.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin, yes, right, I've edited accordingly.

Comment: I don't know if you know about Sylow theorems. Would that be what you would call practical or do you mean some real world applications?

Comment: @PythonSage, Sylows would fit my question, not real world application.

Answer (score 1):

As an example of a "practical application" of the eq. $(2)$: if $G$ is a finite $p$-group and $H\unlhd G$ has order $p$, then $H\le Z(G)$.